# Android : WindowManager.UpdateViewLayout() not working

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-windowmanager

I am showing camera preview on top using system alert. And I am trying to make it draggable. Initially I am drawing it on top left conrner. But on dragging it, it just comes to the center of the screen and doesn't move after that.
Here is how I am adding relative layout :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sf_lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(xlen,ylen);
    relativeLayout.addView(surfaceView,sf_lp);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0,0,WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    wLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    windowManager.addView(relativeLayout,wLayoutParams);
```

Here is the code for OnTouch :

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    int xpos = relativeLayout.getLeft();
    int ypos = relativeLayout.getTop();

    if(X >= xpos && X <= xpos+relativeLayout.getWidth() && Y >= ypos && Y <= ypos+relativeLayout.getHeight())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"X="+X+", "+"Y="+Y+"-Touched inside",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                dx = X - wlp.x;
                dy = Y - wlp.y;
                Log.v("onTouch", "Action Down:X=" + X + ", Y=" + Y + " ,dx=" + dx + " ,dy=" + dy);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : Log.v("onTouch","Action Up:X="+X+", Y="+Y+" ,dx="+dx+" ,dy="+dy);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                //windowManager.removeView(v);
                Log.v("ACTION_MOVE","X="+ (X-dx) +"Y="+ (Y-dy));
                //((TextView) v.findViewWithTag("tv")).setText("X="+ (X-dx) +"Y="+ (Y-dy));
                WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp1 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                wlp1.x = X-dx;
                wlp1.y = Y-dy;
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(v,wlp1);
                //windowManager.addView(v,wlp1);
                //v.animate().x(X-dx).y(Y-dy).setDuration(0).start();
                Log.v("onTouch", "Action Move:X=" + X + ", Y=" + Y + " ,dx=" + dx + " ,dy=" + dy);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"X="+X+", "+"Y="+Y+"-Touched Outside",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see in Action Move I have already tried removing the view and the adding it again with new layout parameters but it does the same thing. I can drag a button in an activity with this same code but not this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp1 = wLayoutParams; and put it under onTouch just above X.

Comment: I will try and let you know..

Comment: @k0sh I tried that but it moved very less and then stopped. No ideas why

Comment: @k0sh One more update..with your trick I am able to drag it for longer every time I try it. any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what was causing it. The problem was with the 'if' condition where I was trying to determine if user has touched inside the view or outside. It wasn't updating the location of relative layout after dragging.

```
   int xpos = relativeLayout.getLeft();
    int ypos = relativeLayout.getTop();
    if(X >= xpos && X <= xpos+relativeLayout.getWidth() && Y >= ypos && Y <= ypos+relativeLayout.getHeight())
{

}
```

I commented the if condition and its working as expected. But I am not sure what was problem with 'getLeft()' and 'getTop()'. I also tried 'getLocationInWindow()' but it didn't update the relative layout's location in screen too. If anyone finds the problem please share. And thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
I had tried the same using below code and using surfaceview directly rather than relative layout

preview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    private int initialX;
                    private int initialY;
                    private float initialTouchX;
                    private float initialTouchY;

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                initialX = params.x;
                                initialY = params.y;
                                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                                return true;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                return true;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                                params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);


                                windowManager.updateViewLayout(preview, params);
                                return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```